# Including a library across multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, sdl-2

I have to create a `Character` object in a `Game` class. Both have SDL2 included.

The `Game` class uses SDL for `SDL_BlitSurface` and `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`, and the `Character` class uses SDL for `SDL_Surface`.

Is there a way to avoid redundancy in this include? Will the compiler include SDL2 just once?

Comment: #pragma once at the top of the every header file in your project should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the compiler include SDL2 just once?

If the included header has an *include guard*, then yes.

If the header contains any definitions, then it *must* have an include guard or else including it multiple times would make the program ill formed.

I didn't go through all headers of SDL, but I would assume that every one of them uses an include guard.

> I included "SDL.h" in both Game.h and Character.h. Is it a problem for source health ?

I don't know what *source health* is. If `Game.h` depends on definitions/declarations in `SDL.h`, then it must include `SDL.h`. If `Character.h` depends on definitions/declarations in `SDL.h` then it must include `SDL.h` also. There is nothing wrong with that. It is quite typical.

Answer (score 0):

in the head file,you need add follow code:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
// your code
#endif
```

or

```
#pragma once
```

This can help you avoiding class include more than once!